# Elasticsearch, sum of size of arrays in documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new with Elasticsearch, and i'm useing Java High Level Rest Client.
I have documents with arrays inside, and i want the sum of the size of the arrays of a particular field from all the documents in my index, but I cannot figure out how to do it.
Example of my documents:
{
  name: 'abc',
  lastname: 'def',
  books: [ { firstBook }, {secondBook}, {thirdBook} ]
}
I need the sum of the size of field "books" from all my documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scripted_metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scripted-metric-aggregation-usage.html) aggrgegation for this

Query:

```
GET index31/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "doc_length": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": {
          "source": "state.commits = []"
        },
        "map_script": {
          "source": "state.commits.add(doc['books'].length)"
        },
        "combine_script": {
          "source": "def sum = 0.0; for (c in state.commits) { sum += c } return sum"
        },
        "reduce_script": {
          "source": "def sum = 0.0; for (a in states) { sum += a } return sum"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```